# How to project the lines of a basketball ball on an ancient greek head for 3D printing?

Tags: modeling

Hi people of BlenderStack !
I'm Ben and im looking for help.

i'd Like to recreate this idea on Blender for a 3D print :
[image]

i thought about boolean but it goes too deep or not at all in the head
[image]

If someone understand my problem and have a solution pls help a desperate art french student
bye

---

Update :
with  retopo - multires- shrinkwrap- Sphere Unwrapp - and displacement im here now [image]
with this normal map :
[image]

[image]

i now have to find a way to make it less stretch and in good position

Comment: where they answers? or where those information to be added to the question? The answers section is just for answers, not for anything else.

Answer (score 6):

You could do it with a displace modifier. You just need a displacement map of your texture. I made mine with a normal map which was quickly done from a regular basketball texture so the result is not perfect. You really should use displacement map.

First you need to have enough resolution in your mesh. I had a head which had quite a lot of resolution but it still required 2x Subdivision Surface modifier. The Subdivision Surface modifier should be set to Simple not Catmull-Clark. In my example the deformation cannot be seen because there is a lot of geometry beforehand. Also give your mesh a Displace modifier. Next press New in the Displace modifier.

[image: subdiv and displace]

Press the Show texture in texture tab button in the Displace modifier.

[image: Show in texture tab]

Press Open and find your displacement map.

[image]

Set you Color Space to Non-Color.

[image: Non-Color]

Go back to Modifier Properties panel and in Displace Modifier set Coordinates to UV and decrease the Strength.

[image: Coordinates to UV. Decrease the strength.]

Remember to UV-unwrap your object so you get nice result. Next you can export the mesh from File -> export -> stl. Select Selection Only and Apply Modifiers.

[image: result]

Comment: I rly thank you for your time but im a big newbie and dont know how to do a good normal map, not even a  bad one aha

Comment: Displacement map should be used. Normal map can give you ok results in some cases, but high quality displacement map is a lot better. You can search displacement maps from the internet. A lot of places sell them. You can probably even find free ones for basketball.

Comment: how many faces have your base mesh ? mine with 6 millions doesnt works and i cant/ dontknow how to unwrapped it

Comment: The head I used only had 40 000 faces so that shouldn't be the problem.